# iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.3) not detected by Xcode

Tags: ios7, xcode5, iphone-5, xcode-organizer

I have a iPhone 5 with iOS 7.0.3 and Xcode 5. The device is not getting displayed on Run option of Xcode. However, it is detected by iTunes. I checked 'Organizer' Menu and found yellow symbol adjacent to device. What does this indicate? Also, valid provision profile is show in Organizer for device. I disconnected and again connect but issue still persists. Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you Enabled Developer mode on the device? It should be there in the Xcode Organizer.

Comment: time to start guessing - reboot everything? make sure it's added to the dev portal?

Comment: Tried all Guessing efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I have same experience in Xcode 5.0.2 and iOS 7.0.4
Reboot mac os solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem i solve it ....

your devise connected with mac but not connected with xcode...i hopw i am wright ...so you need...upgrade xcode version ...

your **iphone version is 7.0.3 so  you need xcode 5.1 or more version need** ..... otherwise iphone 7.0.3 **not connected with your xcode less then 5.1 version** ...

Comment: I had Xcode 5.0.x (beta) version and iPhone iOS 7.0.3 working.

Comment: ok... then your problem solve it now......some time it's happen upgrade problem that's why i am saying.... :)